# Celery: communicating between tasks (and clients) with kombu

Tags: python, django, celery, messaging, kombu

This is frustrating me some and costing me a great deal of time in research, and reverse engineering for lack of Celery docs on internals. There is a beautiful, tutorial here:

https://ask.github.io/celery/tutorials/clickcounter.html

that does just this, uses kombu to communicate between a Django view and a Celery task. But it's for Celery 2.6 and well, it's 2020 and we're using 4.4 and this in particular:

```python
from celery.messaging import establish_connection
```

is long deprecated. It also leans on `kombu.compat` when I think kombu natives would work fine here and we don't need to lean on carrot compatibility which that module provides. But that is a side issue.

My main problem is bringing this example up to date, and I find no Celery docs to help and still cannot after hours of code reading and tracing still put my finger on an analog to this in Celery 4.4.

I find hints and clues all over the celery code base, just haven't nailed an answer.

I would be pleased, grateful and excited if a more experienced voice wandered along and shed light on this, helped getting such an example as this tutorial working using Celery 4.4 methods.

To illustrate I found this:

```python
COMPAT_MODULES = {
    'celery': {
        'execute': {
            'send_task': 'send_task',
        },
        'decorators': {
            'task': 'task',
            'periodic_task': _compat_periodic_task_decorator,
        },
        'log': {
            'get_default_logger': 'log.get_default_logger',
            'setup_logger': 'log.setup_logger',
            'setup_logging_subsystem': 'log.setup_logging_subsystem',
            'redirect_stdouts_to_logger': 'log.redirect_stdouts_to_logger',
        },
        'messaging': {
            'TaskConsumer': 'amqp.TaskConsumer',
            'establish_connection': 'connection',
            'get_consumer_set': 'amqp.TaskConsumer',
        },
        'registry': {
            'tasks': 'tasks',
        },
    },
    'celery.task': {
        'control': {
            'broadcast': 'control.broadcast',
            'rate_limit': 'control.rate_limit',
            'time_limit': 'control.time_limit',
            'ping': 'control.ping',
            'revoke': 'control.revoke',
            'discard_all': 'control.purge',
            'inspect': 'control.inspect',
        },
        'schedules': 'celery.schedules',
        'chords': 'celery.canvas',
    }
}
```

here: https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/local.py

which is a tantalizing clue that `celery.messaging.establish_connection` was replaced with ... `connection` ... though interpreting that is hard.

The Celery app created when instantiating Celery:

```python
app = Celery('current_module', broker='pyamqp://mybroker', backend='rpc://')
```

has a `connection` attribute, and yet `app.connection` does not replace `connection = establish_connection()` in this tutorial (life's not that simple).

I'll continue studying this and trying to work it out, but I want to invite anyone who might save me time and effort with some pointers to help out, with some sample code that opens a kombu connection and sends a message in one function (say a Django view) and opens a kombu connection and receives the message in another function (say a Celery task) either from scratch (ignore Celery) or far more ideally using Celery (as Celery already has all the configs for the broker in place and probably got helper functions for doing just that.

One candidate might be Celery's `Queue` or `SimpleQueue` classes but they lack internal documentation of any kind I can find.